# if two matrices have the same solution space, do they have the same nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B ∈ M_{m×n}(F)$, and suppose $b ∈ F^m$. If the solution sets $\{x : Ax = b\}$  and
$\{x : Bx = b\}$ are nonempty and equal, does it follow that $N(A) = N(B)$?

Unless $b=0$, I don't think this is true. How can I prove this for some fixed non-zero b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $x_n\in N(A)$. If $x_o$ is a solution, then $x = x_0+ x_n$ is also a solution for $Ax=b$ where $x_o$. There $x_0+x_n$ should also be a solution for $Bx=b$. So $Bx = Bx_0 + Bx_n$. But $Bx_0=b$ which implies $Bx_n = 0$ as well. You can extend this argument for the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The solution set of $Ax=b$ is $x_0+N(A)$, where $x_0$ is one solution.